# How to fix sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize... Original exception was: viewonly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following app.py:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON
import os
from psycopg2.extras import Json, DictCursor


class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'secret_key'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or 
    'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost:5432/gkrs_test'


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Teacher(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teacher'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    classes = db.relationship('Classes', back_populates='teacher', lazy='dynamic')


class Classes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'classes'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    teacher = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teacher.id'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    day = db.Column(db.String(20))
    time = db.Column(db.String(20))
    students = db.Column(JSON)


class Viktorina(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'viktorina'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    teacher = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teacher.id'))
    questions = db.Column(JSON)
```

When I go to python console and use:

```py
>>>from app import db
>>>from app import Teacher, Classes, Viktorina
>>>Teacher.query.get(1)
```

I get the following exception:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\PycharmProjects\gkrs-viktorina\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 512, in __get__
    mapper = orm.class_mapper(type)
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\PycharmProjects\gkrs-viktorina\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\base.py", line 451, in class_mapper
    mapper = _inspect_mapped_class(class_, configure=configure)
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\PycharmProjects\gkrs-viktorina\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\base.py", line 430, in _inspect_mapped_class
    mapper._configure_all()
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\PycharmProjects\gkrs-viktorina\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 1352, in _configure_all
    configure_mappers()
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\PycharmProjects\gkrs-viktorina\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 3295, in configure_mappers
    raise e
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class Teacher->teacher'. Original exception was: viewonly
```

I am sure that the tables are not empty, and all have at least one line in them.
How do I solve this issue? I am using Postgresql.
The stuff I found all around the web, didn't help, as none of them had the viewonly exception.

Comment: I believe this has to do with using the back_populates. Try removing that and see what happens. [reference](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5149)

Comment: doesn't do anything

Comment: I tried adding this flag: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.viewonly:~:text=viewonly%3DFalse%20%E2%80%93

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
classes = db.relationship('Classes', back_populates='teacher', lazy='dynamic')
```

you tell SQLAlchemy to create the field 'teacher' in the 'Classes' model, but this field already exists in the classes model due to this line:

```
teacher = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teacher.id'))
```

Perhaps you meant to call the one in the Classes model teacher_id instead?

Comment: I wanted it to be one line, not 2